Is it ok if multiple http clients contain same http client name in .NET?
Is it ok to use the same httpClientName for multiple HTTP clients in .NET?
In a case where I want to group similar kinds of HTTP clients and do some operations in logging, I am using refit client and passing httpClientName to this method overload.
This is the code that I accessed by clicking Go To Definition
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddRefitClient(
         this IServiceCollection services,
         Type refitInterfaceType,
         Func<IServiceProvider, RefitSettings?>? settingsAction,
         string? httpClientName = null)
 {
     var settingsType = typeof(SettingsFor<>).MakeGenericType(refitInterfaceType);
     var requestBuilderType = typeof(IRequestBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(refitInterfaceType);
     services.AddSingleton(settingsType, provider => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SettingsFor<>).MakeGenericType(refitInterfaceType)!, settingsAction?.Invoke(provider))!);
     services.AddSingleton(requestBuilderType, provider => RequestBuilderGenericForTypeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(refitInterfaceType).Invoke(null, new object?[] { ((ISettingsFor)provider.GetRequiredService(settingsType)).Settings })!);

     return services
         .AddHttpClient(httpClientName ?? UniqueName.ForType(refitInterfaceType))
         .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder =>
         {
             // check to see if user provided custom auth token
             if (CreateInnerHandlerIfProvided(((ISettingsFor)builder.Services.GetRequiredService(settingsType)).Settings) is { } innerHandler)
             {
                 builder.PrimaryHandler = innerHandler;
             }
         })
         .AddTypedClient(refitInterfaceType, (client, serviceProvider) => RestService.For(refitInterfaceType, client, (IRequestBuilder)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(requestBuilderType)));
 }


The short answer is no. ;)
To better understand how it works, you have to look at the the source code. Whenever you register an HttpClient (either named or typed) they end up in HttpClientMappingRegistry.
It has the following property:
public Dictionary<string, Type> NamedClientRegistrations { get; } = new();

This dictionary stores the registered clients and the name is used as a key.
There is a private method called ReserveClient inside the HttpClientBuilderExtensions which tries to (re-)register HttpClient.
private static void ReserveClient(IHttpClientBuilder builder, Type type, string name, bool validateSingleType)
{
    if (builder.Name is null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(AddTypedClient)} isn't supported with {nameof(HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults)}.");
    }

    HttpClientMappingRegistry registry = GetMappingRegistry(builder.Services);

    // Check for same name registered to two types. This won't work because we rely on named options for the configuration.
    if (registry.NamedClientRegistrations.TryGetValue(name, out Type? otherType) &&

        // Allow using the same name with multiple types in some cases (see callers).
        validateSingleType &&

        // Allow registering the same name twice to the same type.
        type != otherType)
    {
        string message =
            $"The HttpClient factory already has a registered client with the name '{name}', bound to the type '{otherType.FullName}'. " +
            $"Client names are computed based on the type name without considering the namespace ('{otherType.Name}'). " +
            $"Use an overload of AddHttpClient that accepts a string and provide a unique name to resolve the conflict.";
        throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
    }

    if (validateSingleType)
    {
        registry.NamedClientRegistrations[name] = type;
    }
}

Depending on the  validateSingleType it either simply overwrites the current data or throws an exception.
